# loop over dataframe to sort out sample from a list and do calculation

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a dataframe "testdata" with collected experiment data for different samples.
I would like have a function that grab the first value of a specific column for each sample and calculate the % change for that number and save the result in a new column.

```
samplename=[smpl_1, smpl_2, smpl_3]
```

The dataframe with collected data called `testdata`

```
sample_ID value1  value2
smpl1      3.5     96
smple1     3.5     67
sampl2     3.5     92
sampl2     3.5     87
```

I have tried this, it doesn't work but I'm stucked and need help

```
def test_info(samplename, testdata):


for sample in samplenames:

    testdata = testdata.loc[testdata['sample_ID']==sample]              
    first = testdata.loc[(testdata['cycle']==1)][('capacity')].to_numpy()
    testdata['fading_%'] = (testdata['capacity']) / first * 100
  
    return(testdata)
```

I would like to have a result like this:

```
sample_ID value1  value2 change%
smpl1      3.5     96       100
smple1     3.5     67       69.8
sampl2     3.5     92       100
sampl2     3.5     87       94.6
```

Comment: What are the  'cycle' and 'capacity' columns? Can you check if 'sample_ID` is consistent please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
  sample_ID  value1  value2
0   sample1     3.5      96
1   sample1     3.5      67
2   sample2     3.5      92
3   sample2     3.5      87
4   sample2     3.5      85
```

You can use `groupby`:

```
df['change%'] = (df.groupby('sample_ID')['value2']
                   .transform(lambda x: x.iloc[1:] / x.iloc[0] * 100)
                   .fillna(100).round(2))
print(df)

# Output
  sample_ID  value1  value2  change%
0   sample1     3.5      96   100.00
1   sample1     3.5      67    69.79
2   sample2     3.5      92   100.00
3   sample2     3.5      87    94.57
4   sample2     3.5      85    92.39
```